# Error 400 calling SP2013 rest api

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-rest-api

I'm trying to execute a simple GET request against SharePoint 2013 rest endpoint, but for some reason it returns an error code 400 and says:

> "Request Error: The server encountered an error processing the request. See server logs for more details".

[image: BadRequest message image]

It says "see server logs", but there are no mentions of "error" and "exception" keywords in the standard SP logs at `_C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\15\LOGS_`

Also this message is shown regardless of which *api* based url I'm trying to query.

Any thoughts how I could troubleshoot that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I found a solution eventually. For some reason a reinstall of the [WCF Data Services 5.6](http://jpwaldin.com/blog/?p=236) solved the problem. Seems it was broken somehow.